# scipy curve_fit fails on easy linear fit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I intend to do a simple linear fit with two numpy arrays `y1` and `y2` of length 54 each. The function is defined as follows:

```
def f(x,b):
    return b*x
```

The data are plotted here:

[image]

Then I tried fitting via:

```
popt, pcov = scop.curve_fit(f,y2,y1)  # yes y1 and y2 are in right order
```

Result: `popt = 1., pcov = inf`

I tried with `p0 = -833`, which is more or less what the result should be, but it gives me `popt = -833, pcov = inf`.

I tried some sample data with a sample function:

```
x = np.array(range(10))
y = x**2 + 3
def fu(x,b):
    return x**2 + b
po, pc = scop.curve_fit(fu,x,y)
print po, pc
```

Result is just fine: 3 and 2e-33

Does anybody have an idea as to what went wrong with the first trial? I haven't found anything useful or connected to my problem yet...

Comment: Have you checked whether your data contains any NaNs or infinite values?

Comment: yes, there are NaNs. does curve_fit not have an NaN handler?? is there a work around?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy-optimize-curve-fit): "`check_finite` : bool, optional
If True, check that the input arrays do not contain nans of infs, and raise a ValueError if they do. Setting this parameter to False may silently produce nonsensical results if the input arrays do contain nans. Default is True."

Comment: @wflynny that argument was added in scipy v0.15.0 - OP might have an older version

Comment: @Robert: the NaN issue is a good example of why you should give a [mcve] rather than just post a plot-- the problem came down to a fact about your data that you didn't think to mention and someone had to guess.

Comment: One clue that there are NaNs in your data is the fact that there are only 50 points  in your plot, whereas you said your arrays were of length 54 - NaN values are usually rendered as invisible by matplotlib. @DSM is absolutely right, though - if you had attempted to create an MCVE from your data then there is a good chance you would have figured out the cause of the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NaN values will produce meaningless results - you need to exclude them from your data before doing any fitting. You use boolean indexing to do this:

```
valid = ~(np.isnan(y1) | np.isnan(y2))
popt, pcov = scop.curve_fit(f, y2[valid], y1[valid])
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, [in versions of scipy newer than 0.15.0](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3422) `curve_fit` will automatically check for NaNs and Infs in your input arrays and will raise a `ValueError` if they are found. This behavior can be optionally disabled using the [`check_finite` parameter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Based on your question and comments, I'm assuming you must be using an older version - you should probably consider upgrading.